# MYSQL Read and Write to different tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that e-mails the form data to a e-mail address. I am also wanting to store this information into a database. The problem I am running into is I am pulling information from one table, online_rental_db so that the information from that can be sent to us. I am wanting to also store the form information into another table online_rental_request.

```
<?php

$rentID = $_POST['current_id'];

$db=mysql_connect ("localhost","test","test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("rentals");

$table="online_rental_db";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rentals = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$description = ucwords(strtolower($rentals['Description']));
$image = $rentals['Image'];
$download = $rentals['PDF'];
$bytes =  filesize($rentals['PDF']);
$ID = $rentals['ID'];
$CTGID = $rentals['CTGID'];
$category = $rentals['Category'];
$model = $rentals['model'];
```

I have tried using on the $sql to do

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID INSERT INTO online_rental_request (name, email, id, description, model, category) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$rentID','$description','$model','$category')";
```

but it gives me a sql error!

Comment: Remove `SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID` from your `$sql`, so it starts with `INSERT INTO` and it should insert fine.

Comment: So are you meaning this? $sql = "INSERT INTO online_rental_request (name, email, id, description, model, category) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$rentID','$description','$model','$category') SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID"; I know that just using INSERT works, but I am needing the information from the other table also like description, category, model, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to insert into the online_rental_request table directly from online_rental_db table, you should do the following:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO online_rental_request (name, email, id, description, model, category) SELECT '$name', '$email', id, description, model, category FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID";
```

By the way, you should not forget to escape your user-submitted values. You should do this:

```
$rentID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['current_id']);
```

OR, better
    $rentID = (int)$_POST['current_id'];

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO online_rental_request (name, email, id, description, model, category) SELECT '$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]', id, description, model, category  FROM $table WHERE ID=$rentID ";
```

so it is the format of:

```
INSERT INTO online_rental_request (name, email, id, description, model, category) 
SELECT 
   '$_POST[name]',
   '$_POST[email]', 
   id, 
   description, 
   model, 
   category 
FROM $table 
WHERE ID=$rentID
```

and that way you are able to specify the name and email yet can insert the information from `$table` and insert it into `online_rental_request`.